# Shortcode Not Working in Slider When Added To Post Title

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, get-the-title

I've coded a shortcode to add manually to specific post title fields so i can style part of a title

```
add_shortcode( 'green', 'green_shortcode' );
function green_shortcode( $atts, $content = 0 ) {

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'green',
    ), $atts );

    return '<span class="' . $a['class'] . '">' . $content . '</span>';
}
```

This works on the single post titles but doesn't parse the shortcode when pulling the title into a slider.

This is the messed up HTML output from the slider

```
<h2><a href="http://newlocal.local/this-is-a-featured-post-4/" title="This  is a Featured Post #4">This <span class="green"> is a Featured Post #4</span></a></h2>
```

Here's a visual

[image]

I have added do_shortcode to the post title PHP but it doesn't fix the problem

```
do_shortcode( get_the_title() );
```

The slider uses a WP_Query

```
new WP_Query( $query_args );

printf( '<h2><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></h2>', get_permalink(), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), get_the_title() );
```

**Edit :** This is whats added to functions.php to parse shortcodes in the post title. Works in single post titles but NOT when the post title is shown in a slider.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 1):

[`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) returns the content you pass it with the shortcodes, if any, filtered out (ie, processed).

So the code you've posted in your question won't work the way you want it to:

```
do_shortcode( get_the_title() );
printf( 
    '<h2><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></h2>',
    get_permalink(),
    the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ),
    get_the_title() 
);
```

Instead you'll need to do something more like this:

```
$title = do_shortcode( get_the_title() );
printf(
    '<h2><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></h2>',
    get_permalink(),
    the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ),
    $title
);
```

or

```
printf(
    '<h2><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></h2>',
    get_permalink(),
    the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ),
    do_shortcode( get_the_title() )
);
```

Comment: No, that's what i tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/386212/edit) to show the full code snippet that you're having trouble with. As it stands, it doesn't look like you're using `do_shortcode()` correctly.

Comment: the_title filter is used to allow sortcodes in titles